# Hiding text with JS

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I asked this in another thread and got some helpful advice. I'm re-posting this because I'm not getting any traction on the other post.

I have a small line of html that opens a side nav bar:

```
<div id="main">
        <span id="open" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer">&#9776; Open</span>
        <img class="imgcenter" src="/images/eggs.jpg">
        <p>Where </p>
        <img class="imgcenter" src="/images/eggs.jpg">

      </div>
```

The corresponding js for this html that is supposed to show hide "Open" when ☰ Open is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", function openMainNav() {
document.getElementById("myMainNav").classList.add('sideNavOpen');
document.getElementById("main").classList.add('lmarg250');
var x = document.getElementById("open");
if (x.innerHTML === "&#9776; Open") {
  x.innerHTML = "&#9776;";
} else {
  x.innerHTML = "&#9776; Open";
}

});
```

I was instructed to remove the "onclick" inside the hmtl because it is in-secure and also my var x wasn't defined so I've defined it. I've fixed both but I'm un-able to get the "Open" text to hide. I believe the problem lies in how i've grouped my elements or how i'm assigning my ID's? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your question a little. You are comparing a charcode to a string representation of the charcode. You can use [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to get the character and match it.

```js
document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let span = document.getElementById("open");
  if (span.innerHTML === String.fromCharCode(9776).concat(" Open") )
    span.innerText = String.fromCharCode(9776);
  else
    span.innerText = String.fromCharCode(9776).concat(" Open");

});
```

```html
<span id="open" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer">&#9776; Open</span>
```

*PS: If you are using a callback function there is no need to name it.*

Comment: Relying on text content for doing comparisons isn't a good approach. Instead, is much better to rely on a HTML attribute.

Comment: why using `let` if you're not reassigning the variable? also a bad practice.

Comment: @Diogo Lessa Yes class based selection would be better. But the bug in the code is caused by the comparison.

Comment: @Diogo Lessa In the real code the `span` variable would probably be reused. It has more brevity, is more efficient and avoids (future) duplication. So why would this be a  bad practice?

Comment: reused is different than reassigned.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but how do I get the console.log result to print in the hmtl. And what you are saying is that the charcode isn't being interpreted correctly and this code fixes it?

Comment: @Dangeruss I changed it to reflect changing the text in the span. You could add html using `span.innerHTML` instead of `span.innerText` if you really need to add HTML opposed to a string (text).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I believe your best approach would be to rewrite the text content base on an attribute/class, instead of a text. Take a look on the example:

```
<span id="open" data-opened="false" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer">&#9776; Open</span>
```

```
const menuBtn = document.getElementById('open');

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  if (menuBtn.getAttribute('data-opened') === 'false') {
    menuBtn.innerHTML = '&#9776;'
    menuBtn.setAttribute('data-opened', 'true')
  } else {
    menuBtn.innerHTML = '&#9776; Open'
    menuBtn.setAttribute('data-opened', 'false')
  }
})
```

Example: https://codepen.io/lessadiogo/pen/BayELYQ

Cheers,

Comment: `menuBtn.setAttribute('class', 'opened')` will replace all assigned classes. This might lead to hard to fix bugs. You want to use something like `menuBtn.classList.toggle('opened')` instead.

Comment: `classList.toggle` isn't a standard implementation. I am just answering for his needs. This element doesn't have any classes. If he understands the idea, he can come up with this later. I really don't see why overload with this right now.

Comment: just to keep my idea completely acceptable, I've changed the example to use a data-* instead.

Comment: @DiogoLessa your solution works though It seems that I need to click the button twice in order to have the function remove the word "Open"

Comment: @Dangeruss, I've just opened the pen, and it works.. are you clicking right? Over the hamburger? Also, the response you choose is bad practice, do never compare text, never. Also prefer to user attributes instead.

Comment: Hey @DiogoLessa I implemented it in my js file and it seems need a double click, I'll record a video. I'm very grateful for your advice. As I said, i'm very new with JS. So you're saying that the solution i chose which checks the html against itself isn't the right way to go? Why is it bad practice. Why was RMo saying that your solution might lead to "hard to fix bugs"?

Comment: @RMo said this, because I was using the `class` attribute in order to compare if it's opened or not and changing them. It would be right if you'd using any class on your `<span>` element, because it would replace your previous class. But as you're not using any class, it was totally fine. His solution is weak, because relies on text comparison. If you forget a blank space at the end of `<span>` element, for example, it'll stop working until you tweak the `if` statement again. It is much bug prone. And just to make my answer 100%, I've changed the class attribute to the data-opened.

Comment: Also, there is nothing about "hard to fix bugs", it's just the way he found to explain himself.. Regarding your code not being working properly, it might be something you did while putting my code together with yours... if u want some close support, share your full code online and I'll be glad to help

Comment: Thanks @DiogoLessa i'll attempt to use yours again and see if I can't trouble-shoot it myself. You've been a big help